# Python elementtree append new node: '>' in the text gets modified to &gt;

Tags: python, xml, escaping, elementtree

I'm trying to add a new node to an existing xml.
The node I'm adding looks like this:

```
<Parameter id="SelExpr" value="(some data here)" />
```

This is working.
Some time the node looks like this:

```
<Parameter id="SelExpr" value="(some data >= some other data)" />
```

In this case the xml is showing some changed characters: '>' is changed to `&gt;`.

I tried adding the node creating a new ET.Element:

```
parameters = myroot.find('Parameters')
newNode = ET.Element('Parameter')
newNode.set('id', 'SelExpr')
newNode.set('value', '(' + selectionExpresion.strip() + ')')
parameters.append(newNode)
```

Also tried the following:

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import unescape
parameters = myroot.find('Parameters')
content_str = '<Parameter id="SelExpr" value="(' + unescape(selectionExpresion.strip()) + ')" />'
content_element = ET.fromstring(content_str)
parameters.append(content_element)
```

In both cases when I open the xml with notepad I see

`value="(some data &gt;= some other data)"`,
instead of `value="(some data >= some other data)"`.

Do you have any tips on how I can get `value="(some data >= some other data)"` to appear instead of `value="(some data &gt;= some other data)"`?

Comment: That's how a literal `>` is represented in XML, so it isn't treated as part of a tag name. It shouldn't be a problem, any proper XML parser will decode it.

Comment: if the application reading the xml needs that this string contains '>' and not '&gt;', can this be achieved?

Comment: That should happen automatically when it parses this.

Comment: You should define this part as `<![CDATA[ ..] `, if you would like prevent escaping.

Answer (score 0):

The XML rules say that `<` must always be escaped as `&lt;`, but `>` only needs to be escaped when it appears in the sequence `]]>`. However, it's much simpler to escape `>` regardless where it appears, and that's what most XML serializers do.

Any software that handles `>` and `&gt;` differently is seriously broken, so the only reason for wanting `>` is presumably human readability.

I see that you commented: *if the application reading the xml needs that this string contains '>' and not '`&gt;`',...* Well, in that case the application is seriously broken. If you're going to use XML and get the benefits that it brings, you need to use it properly.